# taking screenshot of a 'zoom' ed image which is not shown completely on screen

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, drawtobitmap

in my winform application i am trying to take screenshot of a image, and assign it to picturebox using DarwToBitmap() method.
it works fine for me, but when i zoom the image and then take screen shot, in picturebox only part of image that was visible on screen is being shown.
how can i capture screenshot of entire image, even if it is zoomed. ??

[this](https://superuser.com/questions/295938/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-an-image-larger-than-the-screen) is very much similar to what i am trying to do.

Comment: Why not just load the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was much more simple than i had expected.
just make zoom to 100% before calling 'DrawToBitmap' and save the image.
after that re assign the prev zoom value.
thats it. works like a charm.